# How can I improve this small Ruby Regex snippet?

Tags: ruby, regex

### How can I improve this?

the purpose of this code is to be used in a method that captures a string of hash_tags #twittertype from a form - parse through the list of words and make sure all the words are separated out.

```
WORD_TEST = "123 sunset #2d2-apple,#home,#star #Babyclub, #apple_surprise #apple,cats    mustard#dog , #basic_cable safety #222 #dog-D#DOG#2D "
SECOND_TEST = 'orion#Orion#oRion,Mike'
```

**This is my problem area RegXps...**

```
_string_rgx = /([a-zA-Z0-9]+(-|_)?\w+|#?[a-zA-Z0-9]+(-|_)?\w+)/

add_pound_sign = lambda { |a| a[0].chr == '#' ? a : a='#' + a; a}
```

I don't know that much Regular Expressions: hence the needed collect the first[element] from the result of the scan -> It yielded weird stuff but the first element was always what I wanted.

```
 t_word = WORD_TEST.scan(_string_rgx).collect {|i| i[0] }
 s_word = SECOND_TEST.scan(_string_rgx).collect {|i| i[0] }
 t_word.map! { |a| a = add_pound_sign.call(a); a }
 s_word.map! { |a| a = add_pound_sign.call(a); a }
```

**The results are what I want. I just want insight from Ruby | Regex guru's out there.**

```
puts t_word.inspect

[ 
"#123", "#sunset", "#2d2-apple", "#home", "#star", "#Babyclub", 
"#apple_surprise", "#apple", "#cats", "#mustard", "#dog", 
"#basic_cable", "#safety", "#222", "#dog-D", "#DOG", "#2D"
]

puts s_word.inspect

[
"#orion", "#Orion", "#oRion", "#Mike"
]
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets unfold the regex:

```
(
   [a-zA-Z0-9]+ (-|_)? \w+
   | #? [a-zA-Z0-9]+ (-|_)? \w+
)
```

`(` begin capture group

`[a-zA-Z0-9]+` match one or more alphanumeric characters

`(-|_)?` match a hyphen or an underscore and save. This group may fail

`\w+` match one or more "word" characters (alphanumeric + underscore)

`|` OR match this:

`#?` match optional `#` character

`[a-zA-Z0-9]+` match one or more alphanumeric characters

`(-|_)?` match hyphen or underscore and capture. may fail.

`\w+` match one or more word characters

`)` end capature

I'd rather write this regex like this;

```
(#? [a-zA-Z0-9]+ (-|_)? \w+)
```

or

```
( #? [a-zA-Z0-9]+ (-?\w+)? )
```

or

```
( #? [a-zA-Z0-9]+ -? \w+ )
```

(all are reasonably equivalent)

You should note that this regex will fail on hashtags with unicode characters, eg `#Ü-Umlaut, #façade`etc. You are also limited to a two-character minimum length (`#a` fails, `#ab` matches) and may have only one hyphen (`#a-b-c` fails / would return `#a-b`)

Comment: Thank you for breaking this down for me.

Answer (score 0):

I would reduce your Regex pattern such as this:

```
WORD_TEST = "123 sunset #2d2-apple,#home,#star #Babyclub, #apple_surprise #apple,cats    mustard#dog , #basic_cable safety #222 #dog-D#DOG#2D "
foo = []
WORD_TEST.scan(/#?[-\w]+\b/) do |s|
    foo.push( s[0] != '#' ? '#' + s : s )
end
```

Comment: This is pretty slick - Though I wish I understood how the regex is broken down. especially the [-\w]+\b

Comment: for [-\w], regex can accept '-' becomes first character in the character set([...]). \b is word boundary meta character. :)